# Which function will be used to destroy the pre define session variable after a certain time?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, which function will be used to destroy the pre define session variable(id, username) after specified time i.e. 20sec?

Comment: You want every session to expire after 20 seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

Ther is no specific function for that, but in `ci/root/application/config/config.php` around line 244 `$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;` this sets your session length. 
Please notice that codegniter sessions are stored in cookies.

If you want to destroy a session after `n` seconds i recommend you to use something else, like:

- [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)
- [ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", SESSION_LIFETIME_IN_SECONDS)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php;)

Comment: The *entire session* is stored in cookies, or just the session ID?

Comment: the entire session, until you use it without the database feature. From that point only a has is stored in the cookie and the rest in a datatable